# How to save the previous MySQL field entry after edit in PHP Laravel 5.x?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model

I'm working with two MySQL tables. Tasks (has the complete MVC) and Task Archives (just a MySQL table), both has the same fields. The only difference is that after editing from Task, I want the pre-updated information to be stored in the Task Archives table and the Task will have the edited entry so as to avoid overwriting from the update.

I did not do an Eloquent ORM relation as I don't need to reference anything from one another. I also did not do a controller nor model to Task Archives as I don't see any purpose to do so unless I would need it to solve my problem.

```
//table fields for task and task archive tables
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('task_name');
  $table->string('task_notes');
  $table->string('task_status');
```

```
 public function edit($id) //from TasksController
    {
        $task = Task::find($id);
        return view('tasks.edit')->with('task', $tasks);
    }
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this ->validate($request,[
            'task_name' => 'required',
            'task_notes' => 'required',
            'task_status' => 'required',
        ]);
        $task = Task::find(id);
        $task->task_name=$request->input('task_name')
        $task->task_notes=$request->input('task_notes')
        $task->task_status=$request->input('task_status')
        $task->save
------->insert code here on how to get the pre-updated information of task and save to task archive table
    }
```

I just want the pre-updated information to be stored in a different table.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new table called `task_audit` and then attach triggers (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`) to your original table to handle the auditing rather than doing this through PHP. [This](https://www.siteground.com/kb/mysql-triggers-use/) article does well to explain triggers.

The `task` table would contain all the "current" data and the `task_audit` table would basically be copies of the rows when changes occur, ideally, you'd also attach a column called `audit_action` so you can differentiate between the action which occurred (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`). You'd attach three triggers (for the three actions) to your "main" table for it record the changed data in the audit table.

Using this method, you'd be able to easily rebuild a task from any date as you have all the archived data and it can be used for reporting too.

Comment: So it would be three tables then? Also how do I attach triggers and where are they supposed to be attached?

Comment: No, it would be two tables, let me clarify further. Triggers are attached to tables, you can use PMA / raw queries to attach create them - the link in my answer should help.

Answer (score 0):

Another method you can use is taking advantage of the [Eloquent model events](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events). By using `static::saved` inside of the boot method, you can access the original values with `getOriginal()` and save it to another table. For instance, here's a mockup of one of mine:

```
class Item extends Eloquent
{

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saved(function($item) {

                $data = [
                    'row_id'            => $item->id,
                    'previous_quantity' => $item->getOriginal('quantity', 0),
                    'new_quantity'      => $item->quantity,
                    'created_at'        => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'updated_at'        => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                ];

                DB::table('update_log')->insert($data);

        });

    }
}
```